# Why don't browsers support custom onbeforeunload message?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

The support for custom text in `onbeforeunload` alert has always been poor and browsers have made it even poorer (with custom text not being supported anymore).

With Progressive Web Apps and all, it seems that such a feature should be pushed forward, as all the apps relying on some kind data synchronisation do probably need to alert the user about the data not being saved.

**What is then the reason for custom alerts during window closing still not being available?**

Comment: In one word... abuse.

Comment: Don't really see how a "Progressive Web App" is relevant to this question. Did you mean the development methodology of "Progressive Enhancement"? If so, it really doesn't apply to this - - it's a way of thinking about implementing new features by first establishing a working baseline. As for `onbeforeunload`, that is a `window` event and there are many aspects of how `window` features are implemented that are not standardized. Yes, all modern browsers implement the event, but they are free to implement it as they see fit since it is a UI issue.

Comment: @ScottMarcus PWAs are striving to offer native-like experience and therefore they often update the UI immediately, while syncing the changes in the background - that's when the relevance of `onbeforeunload` in PWAs comes in in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Originally the return value was used as the message. The [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/browsers.html#unloading-documents) says:

> The `returnValue` attribute represents the message to show the user.

But malware authors put messages in there to scare people from closing their popup windows. They would tell the user that their computer was infected and they needed to download the site's software to clean it; in reality, the software they were telling the user to install was the malware.

So the [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#beforeunloadevent) now says:

> The `BeforeUnloadEvent` interface is a legacy interface which allows prompting to unload to be controlled not only by canceling the event, but by setting the `returnValue` attribute to a value besides the empty string.

It no longer says that the return value should be shown to the user, which gives browsers permission to show canned messages instead, to prevent such misuse. It also standardizes the user experience across web applications within a particular browser. Unfortunately, this means that the UX is different from browser to browser, which can be annoying to app developers wanting a standard experience for all their users.

Comment: *So W3C gave browsers permission to show canned messages instead of the the return value,* Are you sure about that? I don't think the W3C ever had any say in how the client displays messages in modals that are produced by the client and not the `window` object. This is the reason that `alert()` and `prompt()` dialogs don't look the same or have the same client supplied text in them.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The point is that they no longer say that the return value should be shown as a message, this allows the browser to show a canned message.